# Autoform - Update Array of Objects

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I have this Schema (collection: ReleaseForms) defined:

```
  Diseases:{
        type: [Object], 
        optional:true
    },
    "Diseases.$.name": {
          type: String,
          optional:true
      },
    "Diseases.$.description": {
          type: String,
          optional:true
      },
    "Diseases.$.language": {
          type: String,
          optional:true
      },
```

and in example with following content added:

```
ReleaseForms.update({
  "_id": idNewReleaseForm},
  {
    $push:{
      Diseases:{
        name:"Blutverdünnungstherapie",
        description:"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        language: "de"
      }
    },
  });
```

and if i view this via Autoform and say update, it doesn't show me the existing objects like (Blutverdünnungstherapie):
But "Name" shows the existing entry of Name!

```
{{#autoForm collection="ReleaseForms" id="afUpdateReleaseForm" type="update" doc=selectedReleaseFormDoc}}
    <fieldset>
{{> afQuickField name="Name"}}
    {{> afArrayField name="Diseases"}}
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
```

What can I do that I see the existing entries of Diseases and allows me to edit them?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you please check this [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/7Bpc9AKQracCeXSgw/AutoForm-Update-Array-of-Objects)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I did a stupid failure and didn't publish the array, i only published the Name and so the data of the array wasn't available the be shown

Comment: Ok, great to hear you fixed your issue! Have a nice day.